# ASP.NET MVC2 - hook into client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to trigger some custom code when the client side errors are updated using ASP.NET MVC2 client side validation. I've tracked down this function which I want to hook into:

```
Sys.Mvc.FormContext.prototype = {

    // ...

    _displayError: function Sys_Mvc_FormContext$_displayError() {
        if (this._validationSummaryElement) {
            if (this._validationSummaryULElement) {
                Sys.Mvc._validationUtil.removeAllChildren(this._validationSummaryULElement);
                for (var i = 0; i < this._errors.length; i++) {
                    var liElement = document.createElement('li');
                    Sys.Mvc._validationUtil.setInnerText(liElement, this._errors[i]);
                    this._validationSummaryULElement.appendChild(liElement);
                }
            }
            Sys.UI.DomElement.removeCssClass(this._validationSummaryElement, Sys.Mvc.FormContext._validationSummaryValidCss);
            Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(this._validationSummaryElement, Sys.Mvc.FormContext._validationSummaryErrorCss);
        }
    },

    // ...

}
```

How can I override this function such that my code can

- call the original function
- then do some other work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var old_displayError = Sys.Mvc.FormContext.prototype._displayError;
        Sys.Mvc.FormContext.prototype._displayError = function () {
            old_displayError.apply(this);
            // do other stuff here
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm not used to overriding prototype functions, so I was stumped for a bit.

Comment: Was there anything else you had to do to get this working?  I'm trying to do this same thing and the code above doesn't seem to get called when my client-side validation fires.